# keep the placeholder with increasing font size and on center vertically

Tags: html, css, placeholder

```css
.inpsearch{
    border:2px solid #bbb;
    border-radius:14px;
    height:29px;
    padding:0 9px;
}

.inpsearch::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #ccc;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<input type='search' class='inpsearch' placeholder='&#x1F50D'>
```

I need a greater search icon placeholder, but increasing font size it goes to the top border of input.

I tried with padding, margin... without success.

How to keep the placeholder with increasing font size and on center vertically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move your placeholder slightly down using `transform: translateY(2px)`

```css
.inpsearch{
    border:2px solid #bbb;
    border-radius:14px;
    height:29px;
    padding:0 9px;
}

.inpsearch::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #ccc;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:20px;
    transform: translateY(2px);
}
```

```html
<input type='search' class='inpsearch' placeholder='&#x1F50D'>
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to align it perfectly, we apply the same font size to the input, However this would change the input font and we don't want that, however we can change it back on user input, either with JS or more conveniently with just CSS.

I would assume a search input would have to be required, right ?
That would allow us to make use of the `:valid` selector.

```css
.inpsearch {
  border: 2px solid #bbb;
  border-radius: 14px;
  height: 29px;
  padding: 0 9px;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 150px;
}

.inpsearch:valid {
  /* here we can either set it back to "initial" */
  /* or define the font size we want our input to normally be */
  font-size: initial;
}

.inpsearch::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #ccc;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input type='search' required="required" class='inpsearch' placeholder='&#x1F50D'>
<br>
```

The downfall is that you'll have to have a fixed width on the input, so the font-size don't affect it.